# gps approximate alters on bunch of locations stored in sqlite database

Tags: android, android-service, android-location

im new in android im stuck at a point, i have stored locations in sqlite database and retrieve using a cursor.i want to use these locations for proximity alert/notification.eg
i have stored a shopping mall when i will be near enough of this mall a notification pop up on screen. unbale to start how to get alters on multiple locations and how to keep alive tracking for updated location and get notify after application is closed.please give me any start.
i have got all stored locations in variable :

```
private void refreshLocations() {
    try{
     String pla_key = String.valueOf(listforkey2);
    locationcursor=sql.ListWithPlaceonmap(pla_key);

            if (locationcursor.moveToFirst())
              do { 
                   Lati = (int) (locationcursor.getDouble(locationcursor.getColumnIndex("Place_liti")));
                   Longi = (int) (locationcursor.getDouble(locationcursor.getColumnIndex("Place_longi")));


              } while(locationcursor.moveToNext());

    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        ex.toString();
    }
```

i m also getting locations updated continually :

```
public void startButton(View view) {

   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

}
```

i have an other method in my activity for updated locations:

```
public void recordLocation(Location loc) {

    Toast.makeText(tracking_to_do.this,"Lat: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude()) + " Long: " + String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

how i can arrange things for setting the alerts .

Comment: what do you mean by alters here?

Comment: im sorry my mistake that is proximity alert.

Comment: Do you mean you want to compare values coming in from gps to values in a database and alert if they are close enough? Perhaps you should edit your question with an example or scenario of what you want to happen, and show what you have tried